# Remove 'Display: Block" on Mobile

Tags: jquery, resize, slidetoggle

I have a box that appears when a button is a link is clicked. It uses the jQuery .slideToggle() function. I was wondering if there was a way to manually remove the inline 'display:block' style added to the div when the screen is resized to mobile. This is what I have so far.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if ($("nav").hasClass("bt-menu-close")) {

        $('#WeatherBox').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

But when I have the panel up - 'display:block' - and resize the screen it still stays put. Any ideas?

Comment: `$('#WeatherBox').css('display', '');`

Comment: do you want to just hide the `WeatherBox`?

Comment: Yeah but not completely, I just want to remove 'style=display:block' from the div just once. The button to toggle the box is on the navigation and will be on the mobile navigation as well. The problem is that the mobile navigation is a toggle that slides from the left and I don't want the box showing until the mobile navigation is toggled. So basically if the box is open on a desktop I want to hide it once when resize to mobile, but still have it toggle on a mobile screen.

Comment: neither of these solutions worked, the box still shows when I resize the screen to any size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide `WeatherBox`, you can call `.hide()` on it as shown below instead of changing style `display` value

```
$('#WeatherBox').hide();
```

but if you just want to remove `display:block;` then use below code

```
$('#WeatherBox').css('display','');
```

Comment: It seems like this should work but it still doesn't : /

Comment: check is  `$("nav").hasClass("bt-menu-close")`  returning true or not. If this is false then code inside if condition will never run

Comment: It worked! Sorry it looks like .bt-menu-close doesn't get assigned until you actually open the mobile nav button and then close it so I had to add the above code to the reset function they were calling whenever someone clicks the button. So when it removed .bt-menu-open and added .bt-menu-close I had it do the above check but instead have it check if nav didn't have .bt-menu-open and if so then change the display of #WeatherBox to nothing. I then used matchmedia.js to hide the box when the screen goes below 768px, using the code from above as well. So far no issues!